# Unable to saveAsTable in pyspark dataframe : apache.spark.sql.delta.schema.InvariantViolationException error: Exceeds char/varchar type length

Tags: csv, apache-spark, pyspark, delta-lake, azure-synapse-analytics

I am trying to merge 5 dataframes from csv's and creating new dataframe than in the second step I am creating empty table with custom schema, now I am want to load the records from the dataframe.

Here is the step by step details.

1. creating datatframes from all 5 datafromes

```
cr_df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("abfss://abcxxxxxxxxxxxx.dfs.core.windows.net/Position1.csv")
ir_df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("abfss://abc2xxxxxxxxxxxx.dfs.core.windows.net/Position2.csv")
fx_df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("abfss://abc3xxxxxxxxxxxx.dfs.core.windows.net/Position3.csv")
eq_df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("abfss://abc4xxxxxxxxxxxx.dfs.core.windows.net/Position4.csv")
co_df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("abfss://derdi@abc5xxxxxxxxxxxx.dfs.core.windows.net/Position5.csv")
```

2. Merge above dataframes :

```py
merged_df = cr_df.unionByName(ir_df, allowMissingColumns=True) \
    .unionByName(fx_df, allowMissingColumns=True) \
    .unionByName(eq_df, allowMissingColumns=True) \
    .unionByName(co_df, allowMissingColumns=True)
```

3. Create empty table with custom schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE staging.ddr_position_test
       (
        ReportDate            DATE ,
        JurisdictionId        INTEGER ,
        TransactionId         VARCHAR(256) ,
        ReportAssetClass      VARCHAR(30) ,
        ReportTradeSequence   DECIMAL(4) ,
        LoadId                INTEGER,
        DataSourceId          VARCHAR(4),
        Cleared               VARCHAR(50)
) USING DELTA 
PARTITIONED BY (ReportDate, ReportAssetClass) 
LOCATION 'abfss://slv-container@xyzxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dfs.core.windows.net//silver//delta/ddr_position_test/'
```

Step 4: I was getting shcema mismatch error hence I created column datatypes for this merge dataframe, please note I am cant use schema overrite or merge option because i have requirement with certain type of column datatypes and also few columns needs to rename.

```
df = decimal_to_string_Cols_df.withColumn("ReportDate", lit("ReportDate").cast(DateType())) \
        .withColumn("JurisdictionId", lit("JurisdictionId").cast(IntegerType())) \
        .withColumn("ReportAssetClass", lit("ReportAssetClass").cast(StringType())) \
        .withColumn("ReportTradeSequence", lit("ReportTradeSequence").cast(DecimalType(4))) \
        .withColumn("LoadId", lit("LoadId").cast(IntegerType())) \
        .withColumn("CreatedTimestamp", lit("CreatedTimestamp").cast(TimestampType()))
```

and as final step (step-5) I am writing and saving this like

```py
df.write.mode('append').format('delta') \
  .option("path", "abfss://container@abcdxxxxxxxxxx.dfs.core.windows.net/delta/ddr_position_test/") \
  .saveAsTable("staging.ddr_position_test")
```

now I am getting this error -
[image]

[image]

After doing some research i believe this error is might be due to null or not null columns (just a wild guess), any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in definition of some of the table columns as with the fixed length - it looks like some value for one of the columns exceeds the specified limit.

So you either need to increase size of specific column(s), or instead of using `varchar(N)` just use `string` type that doesn't have hard limit on the text size.

Comment: Can I alter column width  without deleting the table , for example  if I can "TransactionId"           width from Varchar(256) to varchar (500) without changing the order of column ?